# Install SQL Server 2012 missing vs_Setup.msi from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, setup

I am trying to install **SQL Server 2012 Enterprise** with SQL Server **Data Tools** included.  I understand that SQL Server Data Tools is part of what was formerly known as BIDS.  The installation for SQL Server 2012 prompts me for the **ms_setup.msi** installation file from Visual Studio **2010**.  However, I am using Visual Studio **2012** currently only.  The equivalent file in VS 2012 is called vs_professionalcore.msi and is located in Visual_Studio2012_Pro\packages\professionalcore\Setup.

**How can I install SQL Server 2012 with Data Tools having only Visual Studio 2012 given the setup?**  Is there a download or registry entry I need to make? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had Visual Studio 2010 Enterprise on my system when I initiated the setup for SQL Server 2012 Standard. After the SQL 2012 got underway, it stopped and prompted for the VS 2010 setup.msi. At that point, I ejected the SQL Server disc and inserted the VS 2010 setup disc. Then I used the dialog presented by the SQL Server 2012 setup program to browse to the root of the VS 2010 DVD, selected the msi there, and opened it. The SQL 2012 setup continued and when I saw that it was again installing SQL components (rather than VS 2010 components), I ejected the VS 2010 disc (which caused the SQL 2012 setup program to display an error that there was no disc in the drive), placed the SQL 2012 setup disc back into the drive, then clicked the Try Again button. At that point, SQL Server 2012 resumed and after some time it completed successfully.

Comment: He says he needs a download and likely doesn't have the discs

Comment: The question has to do with how to get SQL Server 2012 to completely install when you encounter the error that requests a VS 2010 setup .msi file. Even if you have the disc, it still is unclear what you would need to do to get the installation to complete. I began with "in my case" because I realized it was different from the OP's but that it might prove useful to another reader. I provided details and concluded my suggestion with a report that it worked for me. Sometimes offering-up some ideas of what might work will enable the OP to determine what will work in their situation.